# getting error message from codable struct

Tags: ios, json, rest, decodable

Im am decoding a JSON struct and if it fails to decode, at this point in my error checking it means that one of the fields is missing from the server response, which I want to display to the user.

When decoding this struct:

```
struct UserResponseObject: Decodable {
let message: String
let data: User
}
```

here

```
do {
            let responseObject = try createDecoder().decode(UserResponseObject.self, from: jsonData)
            //print("RESPONSE MESSAGE: ", responseObject.message)
            //print("GET USER DATA: ",responseObject.data)
            completion!(.success(responseObject.data))
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("failure to decode user from JSON")
            completion!(.failure(error))
        }
```

if there is no field .data, I want to return the message in responseObject.message in the catch block. But I am not allowed to redecode the response into this struct.

```
struct ErrorObject: Decodable {
let message: String
}
```

How should I go about trying to get the message when the first decode fails. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can understand the exact nature of error by adding more catch blocks:

```
do {
    let messages = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
} catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
    print(context)
} catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let value, let context) {
    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your struct implemnts codable then you better use JSONEncoder & JSONDecoder

```
struct Language: Codable {
  var name: String
  var version: Int
}

let swift = Language(name: "Swift", version: 4)
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(swift) {
  // save `encoded` somewhere
 }

if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(swift) {
if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
 print(json)
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 if let decoded = try? decoder.decode(Language.self, from: encoded) {
   print(decoded.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any field is missing from the json, you should make it optional first of all. In your case it should be,

```
struct UserResponseObject: Decodable {
   let message: String? // You should decide, should it be optional or not
   let data: User? // You should decide, should it be optional or not
}
```

Also you should handle the no data case in your do block...
As a result in your try-catch block try to create a new instance of `UserResponseObject` object;

```
do {
            let responseObject = try createDecoder().decode(UserResponseObject.self, from: jsonData)
            //print("RESPONSE MESSAGE: ", responseObject.message)
            //print("GET USER DATA: ",responseObject.data)
            if(responseObject.data) {
                completion!(.success(responseObject.data))
            }
            else {
                completion!(.failure(//no data error handler))
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            let responseObject = UserResponseObject(message: error.localizedDescription, data: nil)
            print("failure to decode user from JSON")
            completion!(.failure(error))
        }
```